# Probability of failure of a collection when individual parts can fail

Tags: probability

Here's an example to illustrate the problem that I am trying to solve. I will then explain the part that I am not sure of when modeling this problem:

Information:

- 1 unit of office supply consists of 1 office desk and 1 office chair
- A shipping/transport company has 2 kinds of trucks -- one truck can only carry office chair. Another truck can only carry office desk.
- There is a 5% chance of a truck not reaching it's destination
- Truck carrying chairs can hold 20 chairs
- Truck carrying desks can hold 20 desks
- I, as a customer of this trucking company sent 1000 units office supplies (100 of (1 chair, 1 desk)) to this company.

Questions:

1. What is the probability of 1 office supply reaching destination?
2. What is the probability of all my 1000 units of office supplies reaching the destination?

Answer 1:
prob_chair_dont_reach = 0.05
prob_desk_dont_reach = 0.05

prob_supply_reaches = ((1 - prob_chair_dont_reach)(1 - prob_desk_dont_reach))
prob_supply_loss = = 1 - prob_supply_reaches

Answer 2:
prob_1000_supplies_reach = prob_supply_reaches ^ 1000
prob_1000_supplies_loss = 1 - prob_1000_supplies_reach

Why I am not sure of this answer:

- I believe I am making some wrong assumptions about independence of events here.
- Is prob_1000_supplies_reach^1000 correct? I worry that this is incorrect because if 1 truck does not reach then all the chairs/desks that were in that truck don't reach. Out of the 1000 suuply units, 50 units could be associated with that truck. When I raise it to the power of 1000, am I not double counting?

Comment: Yes, the arrival of one desk and one chair are independent because they travel in different trucks, but the arrivals of $20$ chairs traveling in the same truck are not.  Either they all arrive or none of them do, presumably.

Comment: Thanks. So, how should I fix the calculation?

Comment: If you assume that they put all of your equipment on $100$ trucks, $50$ for the desks and $50$ for the chairs, then you want the probability that all $100$ trucks arrive safely.  Those events *are* independent.